# How to stop a 3d object when collided with another 3d object in unity with inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider

How to stop a 3D object(say a car) falling downwards when collided with another 3d object(say a road). I have tried this the whole day but no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the 3D objects should have colliders, and the car should also have rigidbody component.

Comment: The car have rigidbody with gravity enabled.Also it have a box collider. The road have rigidbody enabled with no gravity .It also have a box collider .Still it is not working

Comment: Please share the configuration of your scene.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I meant, edit your question with screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rigidbody to kinematic or just disable the rigidbody. That can be done by code. This piece stops momentum entirely (which may be helpful to know anyway):

```
rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```

If you ask how to detect collisions, you can do it by using the following method, whereas the "collision" parameter yields data about the [collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html) occurring itself, like the target collider and contacts:

```
OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision) { ... }
```

See also the Unity documentation: [Collider.OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

Comment: Can you suggest a method to do that using inspector

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But it sounds like you should read or watch quite some tutorials for C# and Unity in general - that may resolve a lot of questions you might have in the future.